# Proving set has infimum and unbounded above

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

> **Question**: Determine the boundedness of $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[n^2, n^2+1\right]$, and, if they exist, its infimum and supremum (justifying your answer).

---

I know that $X$ is not bounded above, but is bounded below such that $\inf S=[1,2]$.

How can I prove that it's not bounded above? I feel like I could use the Archimedean property but am not sure how to apply it.

Nor do I know how to prove the infimum. I know $[1,2]\in X$ as for $n=1$, $[1^2, 1^2 +1] = [1,2]$. Is it sufficient to then show that $n \ge 1 \implies n^2\ge 1^2 = 1 \implies n^2+1\ge1+1=2$ therefore $\inf S=[1,2]$?

Comment: Dear @Ruby I think there is some confusion in your question, since $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ not of $P(\mathbb{R})$. Hint: draw the set $X$ in the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $X$ is not bounded above because if $M\in\mathbb R$, there is (by the Archimedian property) a number $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>M$. But then $n^2>M$ and $n^2\in X$.

On the other hand, $1\in X$ and every element of $X$ is greater than or equal to $1$. Therefore $1=\min X$. In particular, $1=\inf X$.

Comment: Why is inf$X=1$ and not $[1,2]$?

Comment: The infimum is always a *unique real number* when it exists. It is never an interval of numbers.

Comment: @LeeMosher So if I find the smallest element of set $A$ is a closed interval $B$, inf$A =$ inf$B$?

Comment: No. The smallest element of a set $A$ of real numers is a *number*, not a set.